# Virtual host with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, virtual, passenger, host

Rails app already works correctly on **mydomain.com** with Apache+Passenger. In addition, I'm going to deploy non-Rails app(wordpress) on **blog.mydomain.com**. So I modified httpd.conf like

```
PassengerEnabled off
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/railsapp/public
  PassengerEnabled on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesn't work. **blog.mydomain.com** also shows Rails app. How can I divide them?

Comment: What do you get when you run:
apachectl -S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of the conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

You might also try swapping the order so the more specific one is first, but look at the section called 'Using the ServerPath Directive' on [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html). It indicates that with older http/1.0 clients, you may not have enough information to route it correctly.